# Change separator colour in UIAlertController action sheet (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uialertcontroller

I'm programming a UIAlertController for a popover on the iPad. I know you can set the background colour of the ActionSheet like this:

`myAlertController.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = myColour`

And you can set the text colour of the buttons like this:

`myAlertController.view.tintColor = anotherColour`

What I'd like to do though is set the colour of the horizontal separators between UIActions. I have looked at the popover's subview hierarchy and I can see that, internally, it uses a UICollectionView.

So **how would I change the separator colour**, be it:

- a hacky way via the subview hierarchy? Or, preferably,
- an official way that I can't see in the docs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no available property for [UIAlertViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html) for customising the separators

You have to go through the subview hierarchy